# How to assign nil to RealmOptional<Int>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have model class something like this and don't know how to assign an swift optional value to RealmOptional, it force me to unwrap the optional. Why I need to unwrap the optional before assign to RealmOptional.

What will be the best option to assign a swift optional to RealmOptional.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Menu:Object {

    var id = RealmOptional<Int>()

    func initWithJSON(json: Any) {

        let jsonResult = json as! [String: Any]

        id              = jsonResult["id"] as? RealmOptional<Int>

    }
}
```

Below the error message that force me to unwrap the optional.

[image]

Comment: You can initialize `Realm.Object` with *parsed* `JSON` [right out of box](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/c:@M@RealmSwift@objc(cs)RealmSwiftObject(im)initWithValue:), you don't need to implement your custom method at all.

Comment: Also, you should set [`.value`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/RealmOptional.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A8OptionalC5valuexSgvp) property of `RealmOptional` instead of replacing it with new value. Because that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't directly modify a `RealmOptional` property, you should always modify its `value` property, which holds the underlying `Optional` value. For this reason, you should always declare `RealmOptional`s as immutable, since `RealmOptional` is a reference type, so you can still modify its `value` property without having to modify the actual reference.

```
class Menu:Object {

    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()

    func initWithJSON(json: Any) {
        let jsonResult = json as! [String: Any]
        id.value = jsonResult["id"] as? Int
    }
}
```

Or even better, make `RealmOptional` conform to `Codable` and then you'll be able to make `Menu` conform to it as well.

```
extension RealmOptional: Codable where Value:Codable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let value = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Value.self)
            self.init(value)
        } catch {
            if case DecodingError.valueNotFound(_, _) = error {
                self.init(nil)
            } else {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(value)
    }
}

class Menu: Codable {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can try to

```
id.value = (jsonResult["id"] as? Int  ?? 0 )
```

Declaring

```
var id = RealmOptional<Int>()
```

is not an optional it will if you declared it like

```
var id:RealmOptional<Int>?
```

it's like doing

```
  var str = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad() 

    str = "" as? String  // will give error
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan, this will work but again if i have defined a property as optional, why I need to give a value always, it can be nil (that it why there are optionals exist)

Comment: `RealmOptional` is hack-type to allow core `Realm` code (which is written in ObjC) to access optional variables of your `Object` subtype. It is not `Swift.Optional` by itself.

Comment: @user28434, then what will be the best option to assign value.

Comment: > `you should set .value property of RealmOptional` This property **is** `Swift.Optional`.